# TYPO3 9.5.x / cms-func

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-9.x

will there be an update for the [TYPO3-CMS /func](https://github.com/TYPO3-CMS/func)  Extension to TYPO3 9.5.x? or is there a different way for using the Features now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This changelog will tell you why there will be no updates

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.0/Breaking-81787-DropEXTfunc.html

It's available here https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/func/

and the introduction of the documentation explains why it will not be updated further

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/func/

Answer (score 2):

Sort pages and create pages have been moved the context menu in the page tree (under "More"). If you have a third party extension which extends the func extension, I'm afraid they will have to be rewritten to use their own backend module.